# Change Active background item color in NavBar flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigation

I'm working on a flutter project and I used scroll_navigation but I want to change background of the selected item and I don't know how. I already change the color of the icon but I want to change the background too. Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

This is my code :

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ScrollNavigation(
        bodyStyle: NavigationBodyStyle(
          background: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(left: Radius.circular(20)),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        ),
        barStyle: NavigationBarStyle(
          position: NavigationPosition.left,
          elevation: 0.0,
          background: Colors.white,
        ),
        pages: [
          Container(color: Colors.blue[100]),
          Container(color: Colors.green[100]),
          Container(color: Colors.purple[100]),
          Container(color: Colors.amber[100]),
          Container(color: Colors.deepOrange[100])
        ],
        items: const [
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.camera)),
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat)),
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite)),
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
          ScrollNavigationItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home))
        ],
      );
    }
```

I want to change the background color of the selected item like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The required type of icon in scrollNavigationItem is type Widget.. So you can wrap your icon with a container and give it a color. Vote if helpful ;)

```
   icon: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  spreadRadius: 40,
                  blurRadius: 40,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2))
            ]),
            child: Icon(Icons.camera))),
```

Comment: can you help me with a code how can I do it

Comment: Give me 10-15 minutes.. meanwhile it would be great if you could share any image that represents your desired output.

Comment: You can check the answer it's a simple workaround not the exact solution.. As it is a very small and less rich library